# How remove homebrew tap

Tags: homebrew

Running `brew tap`gives me a list of registered taps

```
homebrew/cask
homebrew/core
sethdeckard/proj
```

How can I uninstall/remove/delete one of them?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Use `untap`

```
brew untap sethdeckard/proj
```

Comment: I still get this error

`Error: Refusing to untap twam/openfpga because it contains the following installed formulae or casks:
icestorm
prjoxide
nextpnr`

Comment: Sounds like you have installed packages that come from those taps. You'll need to uninstall them first (`brew uninstall icestorm prjoxide nextpnr`) then run the untap command @ajthinking gave.